# DBIOAction[_, NoStream, Read with Write with Read] in Slick

Tags: scala, types, slick, compound-type, intersection-types

Let's say I have the following  action which does at first a read operation and then updates the fields.

`action1: DBIOAction[Any, NoStream, Read with Write]`

Let `action2` do another read operation on the same table. To do the three operation sequentially I do the following:

`val action3 = action1 andThen action2`

So I presume the output should be of the format.

`action3: DBIOAction[Any, NoStream, Read with Write with Read]`

But when I see that the output is of the form again :

`DBIOAction[Any, NoStream, Read with Write]`

Indeed in the method's signature I wrote  `DBIOAction[Any, NoStream, Read with Write with Read]` but the IntelliJ does not complain. This does not seem correct. Am I doing a mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Read with Write with Read` and `Read with Write` are mostly the same type:

```
implicitly[Read with Write with Read =:= Read with Write] // compiles
implicitly[Read with Write =:= Read with Write with Read] // compiles
implicitly[Write with Read =:= Read with Write] // compiles
implicitly[Read with Write =:= Write with Read] // compiles
```

although according to the [spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#equivalence) they seem to be not equivalent (≡):

> Two [compound types](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#compound-types) are equivalent if the sequences of their component
> are pairwise equivalent, and occur in the same order, and their
> refinements are equivalent.

Looking into compiler:

https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3981

> `RefinedType#normalize` is responsible for flattening nested
> compound types to a flat representation.
>
> Types are normalized during `=:=` in search of a successful result.
>
> This means that `((A with B) with C) =:= (A with B with C)`.

https://github.com/retronym/scala/blob/a9182fbeaf018c1aa0f88f0aee7b921383b746f2/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Types.scala#L1601-L1619

```
private def normalizeImpl = {
  // TODO see comments around def intersectionType and def merge
  // SI-8575 The dealias is needed here to keep subtyping transitive, example in run/t8575b.scala
  def flatten(tps: List[Type]): List[Type] = {
    def dealiasRefinement(tp: Type) = if (tp.dealias.isInstanceOf[RefinedType]) tp.dealias else tp
    tps map dealiasRefinement flatMap {
      case RefinedType(parents, ds) if ds.isEmpty => flatten(parents)
      case tp => List(tp)
    }
  }
  val flattened = flatten(parents).distinct
  if (decls.isEmpty && hasLength(flattened, 1)) {
    flattened.head
  } else if (flattened != parents) {
    refinedType(flattened, if (typeSymbol eq NoSymbol) NoSymbol else typeSymbol.owner, decls, NoPosition)
  } else if (isHigherKinded) {
    etaExpand
  } else super.normalize
}
```

Notice the usage of `flatten(...)` and `.distinct`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But my question would be whether "andThen" is doing the right thing ? Because after using "andThen"  the result is not "Read with Write with Read" but simply "Read with Write ".

Comment: @heuristic123 Yes, `andThen` is "doing the right thing" because `Read with Write with Read` is (almost) the same as `Read with Write` (because of the `.distinct` in the compiler, `.distinct` transforms `Read with Write with Read` into `Read with Write`).

Comment: @heuristic123 I wrote "almost" because from the spec point of view there is no guarantee that `Read with Write with Read` is the same as `Read with Write` but current language implementation is such that it's the same.

Comment: @heuristic123 It's not `andThen` that does or doesn't the right thing. It's the compiler that infers types (`Read with Write with Read`, `Read with Write` etc.).